# How can I count the elements of an array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, count

I try to count the items of my array:

```
  $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      data: {
        "id": id,
      },
      success : function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var count = obj.length;
        console.log(count);
      }
  });
```

the output of data:

```
{"1":"horse","2":"cat","3":"monkey","4":"bird"}
```

the output of count:

```
undefined
```

I expect the output of count to be `4`.

If I try to write `data.length` I get the result `69`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obj is an object to use array proto .length use Object.keys(obj) to return array then use .length to get the count.

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Reference Material
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keys.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

your data is an object, not array. so you can get length like this:
Object.keys(data).length